# Making a hidden input based histogram with javascript (basic js, no libraries)

Tags: javascript, html, svg, histogram, rect

I'm trying to make a histogram based on a HTML hidden input value string, to be turned into a SVG with Rect child elemements via JS code. It started to seem fine but I'm stuck in making the rectangles appear inside the SVG element. I'd like some help if possible.

The HTML Code:

```
<body onload="CreateGraph()">
<figure id="fg1">
<input id="myInput" type="hidden" value="1 1 1 1 4 4" name="string" />
<figcaption><br />חנויות אופניים<figcaption>
</figure>
```

And here is the Javascript I managed to formulate until now:

function CreateGraph() {

```
var array=document.querySelector("#myInput").value; 
var arraySplit= array.split(' ');
console.log(arraySplit);
var histogram = document.getElementById("fg1");
histogram += '<svg id="sv1">';
console.log(histogram);
 for (var i = 0; i < array.lenght; i++) {
    histogram += '<rect class="hist">'; 
        
 console.log(histogram);
}
histogram += "</svg>";
```

}

Here is another version that also didn't went well:

```
function CreateGraph() {

    var array=document.querySelector("#myInput").value; 
    var arraySplit= array.split(' ');
    console.log(arraySplit);
    var figure = document.getElementById("fg1");
    console.log(figure);
    HistogramBG = document.createElement("svg");
    HistogramBG.setAttribute("id", "sv1");
    console.log(HistogramBG);
    figure.appendChild(HistogramBG)
    console.log(figure);
    var histogramBars;
    var value = 0;
     for (var i = 0; i < array.lenght; i++) 
            {
            var value = value + array[i];
            console.log(value);

            histogramBars = document.createElement("rect")
            histogramBars.setAttribute("class","hist");
            histogramBars.setAttribute("x", 5)
            histogramBars.setAttribute("y", 5)
            histogramBars.setAttribute("witdh", 10)
            histogramBars.setAttribute("height", 50)
            console.log(histogramBars)
            HistogramBG.appendChild(histogramBars); 

console.log(histogramBars)
    }
   }
```

Please, help me if you can!

Comment: array.lenght is a typo, presumably you mean array.length

Comment: Also [you need to fix this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46788220/1038015)